# how to appened text in textarea in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add some text in textarea. Here is my code

```
    <div id="panel">
        <textarea class="textareaMessage" ng-model="textEntered.text">
        </textarea>
   </div>
```

Here, the text entered is storing in textentered.text model. I wanted to display some space to enter  text followed by display some original text. I have an object "oldMessage" has all the details to display. how to do this type of functionality in angularJs.

Comment: sorry. forgot to add code.<textarea class="textareaMessage" ng-model="textEnetred.text">

Comment: you could initialize your model with the old text? `$scope.textEnetred.text = oldMessage"`

Comment: I would like to help you, but I don't understand